# How to set dropdown box on website so that select option and scrape data

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

A website has changed so I can't scrape data from it anymore. Just need to change the set line below I believe but have tried a number of things and none have worked. I'm not very knowledgeable about this area I'm afraid but rest of code is working. Eg url is https://www.gurufocus.com/stock/CFWFF/insider and it is the table of insider transactions I am trying to press the dropdown for and change it to 100 instead of 10:

```
t = Timer
noTable = 0
Do
    Set DropDown = doc.querySelectorAll(".el-dropdown-menu__item")
    lastDropDrownItemIndex = DropDown.Length - 1
    If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then
        noTable = 1
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop While lastDropDrownItemIndex < 1
If noTable = 1 Then GoTo noTableEscape
DropDown.Item(lastDropDrownItemIndex).Click
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so, not sure what you are after exactly, but the website you're scraping offers an API which in my opinion could probably make your life a lot easier. To put it simply, this means that it provides an easy way to request for data with the use of some parameters embedded in a URL. It returns the requested data in JSON format.

In the following code I will be using the XMLHTTP request method and a JSON Parser. For this you will need the following:

1. [JSON parser](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) , it helps you parse the downloaded data. Follow the installation instructions to import it in your project
2. A reference to the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` library. The JSON parser needs it.
3. A reference to the `Microsoft WinHTTP Services, Version 5.1` library. It lets you use an HTTP request object.

For demonstration purposes, the following code will only print in the immediate window the first entry's name and position. You can modify the code to fit your needs.

```
Sub test()
Dim req As New WinHttpRequest
Dim jsonResponse As String
Dim jsonParsed As Object
Dim url As String
Dim pageNum As Integer
Dim numPerPage As Integer
pageNum = 1 'You can change this parameter to navigate in different pages
numPerPage = 100 'You can change this parameter to control the number of entries
url = "https://www.gurufocus.com/reader/_api/stocks/OTCPK:CFWFF/insider?page=" & pageNum & "&per_page=" & numPerPage & "&sort=date%7Cdesc"

With req
    .Open "GET", url, False
    .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*"
    .setRequestHeader "Authorization", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("The name of your Worksheet").Range("A1").Value 'I have stored a string that is essential to the request in cell A1
    .send
    jsonResponse = .responseText
End With
Set jsonParsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonResponse)
Debug.Print jsonParsed("data")(1)("name") 'get the name parameter of the first entry
Debug.Print jsonParsed("data")(1)("position") 'get the position parameter of the first entry

End Sub
```

Please note that there's a very long string which is essential to the request, which I have stored in cell A1. This string looks like so:

> Bearer
>   eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImUxYjAwMmYxMjczMGRiMTBmMmZkYjJkNDk0YTU4NjRmZDZjOWY3ZGI4ZmI1NDY1NTQ2MzZlMGJhNzkxODUxNmY4NTM2ZWIzZDNhODhmN2VmIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIyIiwianRpIjoiZTFiMDAyZjEyNzMwZGIxMGYyZmRiMmQ0OTRhNTg2NGZkNmM5ZjdkYjhmYjU0NjU1NDYzNmUwYmE3OTE4NTE2Zjg1MzZlYjNkM2E4OGY3ZWYiLCJpYXQiOjE1NTkwNzA3OTcsIm5iZiI6MTU1OTA3MDc5NywiZXhwIjoxNTY5NDM4NzkzLCJzdWIiOiIiLCJzY29wZXMiOltdfQ.mZ4DqhUk9YAU6JYDBScF8MJ_zHPyL94bAec7LxZTaWipcWf9uesdGDMDC9v_7W-6zrtXAUWhk4YAL70E5rpPjM7gusYH0RfO48O2PnaV8gsqXoNCFwFBOHuxh109q7X0YsNkfX2wX8m3XigtK9A_YAGID7wxgX96lwzBevsDJ3borHMcJlQtxidF_Bq2D5WPASsuy3jdY80HkOCR1y4eaSIswBEtK5rPj_xy7VXRbYGhLklqw4wgHgq4blfaHnVVmPXf6k8mx45ye8vPecS-w9kjuDOHVn2mvU6mpBzqEpbH4lqpiqmYG7M-CvB1joEAcMQtcilCvsdfKOusoC2MU4_vPtF3Q4ZFVaEcXIQgomdKtFa_XGpCudit45b2rEFacKMUENqLj_sPwYkgM1IPl1lQfR-VpigqnCHPAxVQAPzqwJvS6CxuYOPmvnrx23fBAillP7LtDHwHtlMpgZUjdB5y6IWsia76crM4kbkrKn3zc8xoAGb1fIrgJlY-9hOzrwsmrchantEdYOFZjcMJvhCnlfvnEm6kT2Sdcu4o6TndTZJjrVmD4mb-jNGy4kw_mAx1DfyqR7GLtCVSzcSLKgrrwCJEL22K2bfXH2HExXvgLFbPXivVZJc70TnF9lJmx_dx79cxAm7szFGIdrs56bAC4mdKpvKL3BNmVY-J-G0

The same string should work for you as well.

The result looks like so:

```
Brown, James Michael
Senior Officer
```

Each one of the 100 data entries has the following structure:

[image]

It's fairly easy to loop through all the entries as well. For example, to print the name of all the entries you would have to do this:

```
Dim item As Object
For Each item In jsonParsed("data")
    Debug.Print item("name")
Next item
```

Finally, you can also loop through all the parameters of each entry. For example, the following code prints all the parameters and their corresponding values for the first entry:

```
Dim key As Variant
For Each key In jsonParsed("data")(1).Keys
    Debug.Print key & ": " & jsonParsed("data")(1)(key)
Next key
```

So this way you can basically  access any parameter you want for each entry.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, all sorted now.